# String length mismatch not giving data in another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a column location in my table. I've used it as a common column to join two tables
1.Factory
2.Inventory
Like
Factory.location = inventory.location
But I'm having a problem..
For example Location in factory table just has 09 where inventory table has 009 doesn't match but for three digit numbers it's matching eg: 115 = 115, 999=999. But in the output, I still get 009 but I'm not getting data in another column for the ones which doesn't have three digits.
Please tell me how to make it 3 digit and join.
I tried putting it as
(Case when
length(factory.location)<3
Then concat('0',factory.location)
else inventory.location
End) as location
in select statement.

Please help

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to the question for better response.

Comment: Also add a sample query that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're storing them as `varchar` for a reason, you could pad them to equalize length before matching. I chose 3 because it sounded like all the locations are 3 characters long. Change as required

```
lpad(f.location, 3, '0') = lpad(i.location, 3, '0')
```

If the values in location columns are all numbers that can be treated as integers, you could also do

```
f.location::int = i.location::int
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.. it worked. Also I would like to know if there's any other approach for the same

Comment: @TechLearner See my edits

Comment: thank you. for varchar is there any other approach?